# Setting min date in jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi I want to set min date in my jQuery datepicker to (1999-10-25). So I tried the below code it's not working.

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: new Date(1999, 10 - 1, 25),
        maxDate: '+30Y',
        inline: true
    });
});
```

If I change the min year to above 2002 than it will work fine but if I specify min year less than 2002 (like above example 1999), it will show only up to 2002.
I am using `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` and `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js`.

Comment: To set it after init, use `$('#datepicker').datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date( 1999, 10 - 1, 25 ) )`.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
yearRange: '1999:2012',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: new Date(1999, 10 - 1, 25),
        maxDate: '+30Y',
        inline: true
    });
});
```

Just added year range option. It should solve the problem

Comment: Help me, how to set in backend in odoo.

Comment: what about if i have a mindate as "2019-07-12" string value? how do i set it into the minDate property?

Comment: To answer Fernando, yes you can use a normal date string. You can test with the jsfiddle from below: http://jsfiddle.net/femy8/

Answer (score 19):

The problem is that the default option of "yearRange" is 10 years.

So `2012 - 10 = 2002`.

So change the yearRange to `c-20:c` or just 1999 (`yearRange: '1999:c'`), and use that in combination with restrict dates (mindate, maxdate).

For more info: https://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-yearRange

---

See example: ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kGjdL/))

And your code with the addition:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: new Date(1999, 10 - 1, 25),
        maxDate: '+30Y',
        yearRange: '1999:c',
        inline: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Hiya **working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/femy8/

Now the calendar will only go to minimum of 1999-10-25.

Click on the image i.e. small icon next to text box for calendar to appear. You can try selecting up until 1999 but the minimum date for selection is 25th of oct 1999. which is what you want.

This will help, have a nice one! :) cheers!

**Jquery Code**

```
$(".mypicker").datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: new Date('1999/10/25'),
        maxDate: '+30Y',
        inline: true
});


​
```

Comment: Perfect Solution

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if for example you need to put a min date, the last 3 months and max date next 3 months

```
$('#id_your_date').datepicker({ 
   maxDate: '+3m',
   minDate: '-3m'
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add this for the future programmer.

This code limits the date min and max.
The year is fully controlled by getting the current year as max year.

Hope this could help to anyone.

Here's the code.

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var yrRange = '2014' + ":" + (dateToday.getFullYear());

$(function () {
    $("[id$=txtDate]").datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        yearRange: yrRange,
        buttonImage: 'calendar3.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: new Date(2014,1-1,1),
        maxDate: '+50Y',
        inline:true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#order_ship_date").datepicker({
           changeMonth:true,
           changeYear:true,           
            dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
            minDate: +2,
        });
  }); 


</script>
```

html code is given below

```
<input id="order_ship_date"  type="text" class="input" style="width:80px;"  />
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 1):

basically if you already specify the year range there is no need to use `mindate` and `maxdate` if only year is required