# Set mindate on jquery datepicker (dd.mm.yyyy)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have got a string with the following date format: 23.01.2012

How can I set the mindate to the specified date? Nothing happens if I use the variable directly, and the other posts I've found use another dateformat.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10139771/1418118) answer

Comment: Did you try looking at the API?  It provides you examples of how to do this http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ ..

Comment: Or just check out this [link](http://bit.ly/Wes6nG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var time_value = '23.01.2012';
var values = time_value.split(".");
var parsed_date = new Date(values[2], values[1], values[0]);

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  minDate: parsed_date
});
```

warning: (not tested)

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
var parsed_date = new Date(values[2], **values[1]-1** , values[0]);
```