# How to set minDate of jQuery Calendar Picker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have two date pickers, they are as follows:

**First Date Picker: txtDate**

HTML:

```
Date :  
<input type="text" id="txtDate"/>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        dateFormat: "yymmdd"
    })
});
```

**Second Date Picker: dateAvailable**

HTML:

```
Date Available :   
<input type="text" id="dateAvailable" />
```

JQuery:

```
var dateAvailable = new Date(document.getElementById('txtDate').value);

$(function(){
    $("#dateAvailable").datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        dateFormat: "yymmdd",
        minDate: new Date(dateAvailable)
    })              
});
```

The **Second Datepicker: dateAvailable** should **not be less than** the **first datepicker: txtDate**. So I need to get the date picked at txtDate then set it as the minDate of dateAvailable,

But this is code not working for me..How to set minDate of dateAvailable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139378/setting-min-date-in-jquery-datepicker

Comment: What is the value of `txtDate`?

Comment: Whatever the value that is pick from the txtDate datepicker..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, **[JSFIDDLE DEMO,](http://jsfiddle.net/kGjdL/274/)**

You needed to dynamically change value of the other datepicker, doing what you did was just setting the minimum value of the second datepicker at the time of loading the page at first time.

But when you changed the first datepicker, you did not change the min value of second. To do that you need to use onClose, and change the min value.

```
$(function() {
    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
     changeMonth : true,
     changeYear : true,
     dateFormat: "yymmdd",
        onClose: function(){
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('change',{ 
                minDate: new Date($("#txtDate").datepicker('getDate'))
            });
        }
    })

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        yearRange: '1999:c+1' ,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date(1999, 10 - 1, 25),
        maxDate: '+30Y',
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this will work. the minDate will be 1999, 10 - 1, 25.It should not be less than the first Datepicker..

Comment: @QKWS Also have added why it didn't work for you, hope you understand now why your code did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the second datepicker to have the correct date.

If you assign the value of your first datepicker to be the `minDate` of the second datepicker on page load than it will not have the correct `minDate`.

You can do something like this to update your seconds datepicker to have the correct `minDate`:

```
$(function() {
    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        dateFormat: "yymmdd",
        onClose: function() { 
            // Update the minDate parameter of the other datepicker
             $('#dateAvailable').datepicker('option','minDate',new Date($(this).val()));
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: It's working for me.. I think I'm missing something. I remove the minDate from the second datepicker..