# setting the minimum date in datepicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

i want to set the minimum date in datepicker the day when the application is installed in ios

i.e., if i installed the app on today 21-05-2014, the minimum date in the datepicker has to be  today. So if there is any code pls help me.

@josh Caswell
Please read the question correctly before saying that my question has an answer. I asked to set the minimum date of the datepicker has to the installed date of an app not the today date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you try to user not able to select today's privous date ?

Comment: you can go here if something help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139378/setting-min-date-in-jquery-datepicker

Comment: You can not check on which date you install your app .
you can do one thing that When your App is launched first time Save current date( the date when you open app) and set `picker.minimumdate = yourdate.`

Comment: @Nothing ur link didn't helped me and this question is asked first by me and it doesnt have any answer. Why r u down voting my question?
Who d hell r u Josh Caswell to say that my question has already an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    NSDate *installedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MINIMUM_DATE"];

    if (!installedDate) {
        // This is the 1st time running the app
        installedDate = [NSDate date];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:installedDate forKey:@"MINIMUM_DATE"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

    }



    //Then
    [datePickerView setMinimumDate:installedDate];
```