# How to set min start date in DateTime Picker

Tags: jquery

In my Project,i have dynamic  Started Date & Expired Date,i need to set Expired date min date as specific Started Date

I generate all starded date & expired date by dynamically(it may added By + click & can able to delete)

[image]

There id like this:

```
txtCertificateIssuedDate1,txtCertificateIssuedDate2,txtCertificateIssuedDate3....
```

&

```
txtCertificateExpiredDate1,txtCertificateExpiredDate2...
```

I put this code in `ready function`,so i can able to click date time picker
but how to i handle the expired date min date as that specific start date?..

```
$('input:text[id^=txtCertificateIssuedDate]').datepicker("option","dateFormat", 'mm/dd/yyyy');

$('input:text[id^=txtCertificateExpiredDate]').datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: The minDate will solve your problem. minDate: new Date(mindate). This will help you in your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139378/setting-min-date-in-jquery-datepicker.

Comment: Can you show us HTML?

Comment: @Saranya, did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this when your DOM is ready:

```
$('aCertificateIssuedDateSelector').datepicker({
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        // Set the minDate of 'to' as the selectedDate of 'from'
        $('aCertificateExpiredDateSelector').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$('aCertificateExpiredDateSelector').datepicker();
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6c6uyu37/)

Comment: Thanx in advance ,here what a problem is,how i can find the exact id.......in which id has dynamic no 1,2,3....

Comment: @Saranya, you can use the developer console on your browser to find the id of the relevant CertificateIssuedDate field.

Comment: @Saranya, it is hard to tell you how to get the Id without seeing your View. Generally, if you are using a list/collection/array property, and displaying the first element of that list like `Model.Dates[1]`. the Razor-generate id for that element would be `Dates_1`. You can check this using the developer console on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the minDate param in options

`minDate: new Date()`

It will set the today is minimum date you can pass any date you want. like 1 jan 2001 then

`minDate: new Date(2001, (month - 1)  , 1),`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using -

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '-3M',
        maxDate: '+28D',
});
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());
```

This will help you setting the min date and max date on jquery calendar and setting current date as default selected date. You can set any date a s default date using setDate method.

And for setting things dynamically, check this link

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-set-minimum-and-maximum-date-dynamically-in-jquery-ui-date-picker

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all,

i find a solution,

`$("input:text[id^=txtCertificateIssuedDate]").datepicker().on('changeDate', function (selected) {

            var res =$(this).attr('id').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");

            $("#txtCertificateExpiredDate"+res).datepicker('setStartDate', $('#txtCertificateIssuedDate'+res).val());
        });`