# How to validate year value in datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

**Description:**

I'm using Jquery datepicker in my application, and also user is allowed to enter date by keyboard. Everything is working fine but when user enters 000 or 0000 as year then my code is breaking , because there is no year having value '000 or 0000'.
So, I want to validate value entered by user, specially year value, b'coz date picker is validating date and month and giving an error accordingly but it is not validating year value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139378/setting-min-date-in-jquery-datepicker  !!  i think setting a minimum and maximum may help you.. not sure ..

Comment: mindate, maxdate haven't worked in this case. :-(