# Datepicker: How to validate YEAR?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I already tried searching countless times for this question but none of the answers seem to resolve the issue I am having.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker(
{
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    "setDate": new Date(),
    todayHighlight: true,
    "autoclose": true,
    yearRange: "1990:2100"
});
```

Basically, I have a datepicker, and I want to prevent the user from typing invalid years (eg: 000, 201, 231) so i want to prevent 3 number years basically. I tried putting yearRange but that doesnt work.

Comment: Why are those years invalid? I mean what does your data look like that you can't handle invalid years?  Could 1994 be invalid too?

Comment: Have you tried `YYYY` instead of `yyyy`?  (I could be thinking of month though...)

Comment: There are several jQuery datepicker plugins; judging from the options you're using the bootstrap one?

Comment: basically i just want to prevent 3 number years

Comment: same problem here but no answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385743/how-to-validate-year-value-in-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max), you can specify `minDate` as `-100Y` and that'll constrain the year to within the last 100 years, which would eliminate 3-digit years in 2018.

For the [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it looks like you'd use `startDate` and again, set it to something like `-100Y`.