# jquery UI datepicker: calculate minDate x years from today

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Good afternoon

I am trying to set the minDate for a jQuery UI datepicker, which should be valid for all users aged between 12 and 17. With maxDate alone this works fine. And I know I have to calculate the minDate somehow. I have searched all the other StackOverflow threads, but have not been able to find something similar. The other solutions I have found set a fixed date, but I need it alwyas 12-17 years compared with today.

What I have tried so far:

```
minDate: new Date((currentYear - 12), currentMonth, currentDay))
```

and

```
minDate: "-12y"
```

My current sample:

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    firstDay: 1,
    defaultDate: 0,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '1910:c',
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    beforeShow: function () {
        var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
        var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth() + 1;
        var currentDay = (new Date).getDate();
        
        $(this).datepicker({ 
            minDate: new Date((currentYear - 12), currentMonth, currentDay),
            maxDate: "-17y -11m -30d"
        });
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="myDate">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting min date in jquery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139378/setting-min-date-in-jquery-datepicker)

Comment: NO DUPLICATE, as that thread sets a fix date, not a calculated one as I need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`minDate: "-12y"` works absolutely fine, however if you want to only allow ages between 12 and 17 you need to use both `minDate` and `maxDate` to set the allowed range.

Due to this your use of `onBeforeShow()` is redundant, along with `numberOfMonths`, `defaultDate` and `yearRange`. Try this:

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  firstDay: 1,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
  minDate: '-17y', // min 17 years ago
  maxDate: '-12y', // max 12 years ago
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="myDate">
```

Comment: That's crazy, cause it did not work on my side when I tried this first...???
OK, I'll have a closer look line by line now. Thank you!

Comment: I am using beforeShow because I have to check another parameter first (doing a switch here), then I can set min and max Date according to the given parameter

Comment: In which case it makes more sense to check that before you instantiate the control.

Comment: ok, it works the other way around as well :-) First do the switch, then set min and max date with the filled params. Nice. Thank you for getting me on the right (and easier) track!